# Using Node.js to read a live file line by line

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to determine what is the best way to read a live file line by line.

The line will sent for consumption and then discarded.

The file is live, meaning it is being written to by another application (its a log file).

The file could be large, and therefore I dont want to ready the whole thing in to memory and then process it.

- Read line
- Process it
- Keep required data
- Read next line
  etc..

It seems there are many plugins aka modules.  Not sure what the best (fast and efficient) way is.

I am using node.js version 0.10.33

Thanks

Comment: The question is very general. But I've done something similar, and ended up formatting the data to JSON, then using the [JSONStreamer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/JSONStream) module.

Answer (score 2):

Use [tail](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tail).  It's just like the unix `tail` command, but in node.

```
npm install tail
```

a usage example from the npm page:

```
Tail = require('tail').Tail;

tail = new Tail("fileToTail", "\n", {}, true);

tail.on("line", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

tail.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});
```

Comment: This works good for any new data thats being written to the log file.  It wont process what ever is already in the file.

Comment: The last option to `new Tail()` is the `fromBeginning` option.  If you set that to true it will start reading the file from the beginning.  I've updated the example.

Comment: Copy pasted your code with the parameter changes, the behaviour is the same.  Reads new data not whatever is already there. Could it be that I have a different version of tail? ( I recently installed it )

Comment: Thoughts? Note: I have "version": "0.4.0" installed. :)

Comment: How to identify the last line (before or after reading the line)?

Comment: This does not work for Large Files. I get File does not exist error

Answer (score 1):

you can create read stream http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options
and read before next line. Something like this

```
var lines = [],
  line,
  rs = require('fs').createReadStream('/etc/passwd');

rs.on('data', function(chunk){
  var indx = chunk.indexOf("\n")'
  if( indx !== -1 ) {
      line = line + chunk;
  } else {
      line = line + chunk.chunk(0, indx); //we cut the "\n" symbol.
      lines.push(line); //we add line to array of lines of file
      line = ''; //we clear buffer
  }
});

rs.on('end', function(){
  console.log(lines);
});
```

Comment: This method will read to the bottom of the file.  If it hits the end of the file it stops and throws an error.

Timestamp: 2014-11-07 02:06:30  Random Value 1: 26 Random Value 2: 32 Random Value 3: 32
Timestamp: 2014-11-07 02:06:30  Random has no method 'indexOf'
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> 

Thanks

Comment: Also, if the file is being updated at a slow rate (eg. a line per second), the end of file condition might be hit - even though the file is live and being written too.  Perhaps need to add a timer, if "end" make sure there is no data for at least 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A linux only solution would be to `spawn` a `child_process` of `tail -f /path/to/your/log` and do something with stdout - Not very elegant, but it would work.